# Unable to verify certificate - please set 'ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-s3, environment-variables, carrierwave

I have a Rails 4 application that uses Carrierwave to upload files.  After installing Fog to upload files to Amazon 3, I started getting the following error when uploading files:

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError in VideosController#create

Unable to verify certificate, please set `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] = path_to_file`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_callback] = callback` (see OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#verify_callback), or `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure).
```

I'm confused because I have added 'SSL_CERT_FILE' to my environment paths (under both user and system variables via the Control Panel), setting it to c:/RailsInstaller/cacert.pem (and restarted my computer).

The error is coming up when my controller calls @video.save in controllers/videos_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  @video = Video.new(video_params)
  if @video.save
    redirect_to videos_path, notice: "Video has been uploaded."
  else
    render "new"
  end
end


private

def video_params
  params.require(:video).permit(:name, :attachment) 
end

end
```

I'm on Windows 7, using ruby 1.9.3p484 and RubyGems 2.2.2.  Can somebody help me understand the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @jeff, I think I ended up using the 'carrierwave-aws' gem which provides file uploading capabilities to Amazon S3 as well as Amazon aws-sdk gem functionality.  This allowed me to skip Fog (which I think was causing the error but can't remember exactly).  I don't think I ever figured out how to resolve the certificate error.

Comment: I think you need to define the ENV to your server via the console. In heroku you can do `heroku config:set SSL_CERT_DIR=frfrboxc88b1bd SSL_CERT_FILE=c5707cff6dd5b11a06`

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back but on heroku and solved it with information in https://github.com/excon/excon/issues/239.  What solved it for me was to install the `ca-bundle.crt` on heroku and run `heroku config:set SSL_CERT_FILE=/app/lib/ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: Had a problem with excon errors in the past deailing with fog uploaded and open-ssl ended up being the issue. I had to do this to fix brew update ; brew uninstall openssl ; brew install openssl

Answer (score 0):

Use `RVM` to Fix `SSL` Certificates

Recent versions of `RVM`, the **Ruby Version Manager**, include a utility to diagnose and resolve errors caused by outdated certificate files. See the article Installing Rails for instructions and advice. The `RVM` website explains how to install RVM.

If you have installed `3RVM`, try this:

```
$ rvm -v
 # rvm 1.19.1 (stable)
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
 # Certificates for
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
 # Updating certificates
```

For more on the issue, see a discussion at 
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/pull/1764