# asset_sync/fog Unable to verify SSL certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, fog, excon

I want to use the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem to compile my Rails-assets locally and then upload them to my S3 bucket.
But when I try to compile & upload them the rake task aborts because it's unable to verify the SSL-certificate.

I'm struggling around for 3 days to find a workaround for this problem but nothing solved it.

Found out that the OpenSSL of rubyinstaller.org's builds is [broken](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyinstaller/DVIDvs7xKC0/8dqXCqmABk0J), but  even if I set `SSL_CERT_FILE` [manually](https://gist.github.com/pweldon/767249) the rake task fails with the same error (Even though I can make a HTTPS-connection in ruby with that setting).

**Works:**

```
set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\ruby\cacert_test\cacert.pem
ruby -ropen-uri -e 'puts open("https://www.google.com/accounts").read'
```

**Fails:**

```
set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\ruby\cacert_test\cacert.pem
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

*System: Win 8.1 (x64) and ruby 2.1 (x64) (from [rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/))*

Error-log:

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError: Unable to verify certificate, please set `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] = path_to_file`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_callback] = callback` (see OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#verify_callback), or `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure).
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
...
```

Related:

- [Unable to verify certificate - please set 'ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701632/unable-to-verify-certificate-please-set-envssl-cert-file-path-to-file),
- [How to solve "certificate verify failed" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720484/how-to-solve-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, found a workaround [here](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/130).

Just add to config/initializers/asset_sync.rb:

```
require 'excon'
Excon.ssl_verify_peer = false
```

It's not the safest thing, but it works for my purposes.

Maybe it will work too if I set `Excon.ssl_ca_path` to the OpenSSL CA-directory. I will test that soon and will update this answer when I found out.

Comment: By doing this, you disable Excon certificates check for your whole app (everywhere that Excon is used). This is definitely not a good practise at all and should be emphasised !